# Unable to access git or pip on pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

I'm trying to update some code I am running on PythonAnywhere, but am having some network issues.

When I try and pull from git or install from pip I keep getting errors.

```
(my-site)04:02 ~/my-site (master)$ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/possum-mdr.git/': Failed connect to github.com:3128; Connection refused
(my-site)04:02 ~/my-site (master)$ pip install django_select2 
Downloading/unpacking django-select2
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-select2
No distributions at all found for django-select2
Storing complete log in /home/my-site/.pip/pip.log
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: That was caused by an outage on the proxy server that PythonAnywhere uses to manage web requests from free accounts -- someone inadvertently DoSed it overnight.  It should work fine now.